# The path used during the journey of Prophet Muhammad from Mecca to Medina to escape persecution

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, history, hijra

Are there any historical records in hadith collections or Prophetic biographies, detailing the escape route from Mecca to Medina?

Answer (score -2):

Asalaaam aleikum there is.refer to book called Ar -Raheequl Makhtum(The Sealed Nectar)Biography of the Noble Prophet(Peace and blessing be upon him),page 203-217 with a subtopic The Emigration of the Prophet(peace and blessings be upon him).Shukran

Comment: By Safiur -Rahman Al-Mubarakpuri

Comment: While the book may answer the question this post doesn't (see [answer]).